# Google Maps API V3 でストリートビューが表示できなくなっている。

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Google Maps API の javascript V3 を使い、自作のスクリプトでウェブページにマップを表示させています。デフォルト表示される地図やマーカーは問題なく表示されているのですが、ペグマンをドラッグ&ドロップする形でストリートビューを表示させると、以前はちゃんと表示できていたものが今現在はちゃんと表示されていません。
Google API の[ストリートビューを解説しているこのページ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview?hl=ja#StreetView)と全く同じ状態です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
背景はグレーで、ところどころ三角形の画像が散らばっています。方向などを変えるとその三角形も大きさ・位置が変わりますが、全体が表示されることはありません。

実は、大手グルメ口コミサイトの Retty でもこの現象を目にしており、まさか自分のサイトでも同じ現象が起こっているとはつゆ知らず・・・この現象は広範に発生している可能性があります。

と、ここまで書いてブラウザが Chrome での現象だと分かりました。IE や firefox ではちゃんと表示されているようです。もしかしたら自分の Chrome だけこんな現象なのでしょうか？特に設定関係はいじっていないつもりですが・・・
Chrome のバージョンは 50.0.2661.94 m (64-bit) 。現時点での最新バージョンです。

どなたかご存知のかた、原因と対処法をご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 私の仮想環境のwindows7 pro 64bitにたった今はじめてインストールしたgoogle chrome 50.0.2661.94mでは当該ページのストリートビューは問題なく動作しているように見えます。普段使いのブラウザでなければ、一度アンインストールして設定等を削除してからためしてみてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: あるいは、F12でデバッガを開いて何か出力やエラーがないか確認してみてください。

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。
デベロッパーツールで確認してもエラーは出ていませんでした。
この現象は自宅PC・会社PCどちらでも発生しますので、固有のPCの問題ではないなと。Chrome は設定や拡張機能を自動同期しますのでそのせいかもと思い、一度全部の拡張機能を外したりしましたが同じでした。
しかし、もう一つ別のPCで見たところちゃんと表示できましたので、その差は何なのかもうちょっと調べてみようと思います。

Comment: 私の方でも同様の環境と思われる状態で表示されています。（Win7pro64bit：Chrome最新）　現象が不明なため差し支えなければ問題が発生しているスクリーンショットを添付してください。また、試したかどうかは記載されておりませんでしたがJavaのバージョン、Flashのバージョンも問題が無ければ記載したほうが回答が集まるかと思います。

Comment: スクリーンショット追加しました。
Javaのバージョン、Flashのバージョンはあとで確認します。

Answer (score 1):

JavaやFlashに問題がありそうな気がします。
[Googleのトピックでストリートビューが真っ黒になる問題があったようです](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps-ja/fiXkKjtR6fI/discussion)
下記からJavaを再インストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか？

http://java.com/ja/download/

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。
そのトピックは目にしておりましたが、真っ黒ではなく、灰色の背景に一部画像が三角形の形で表示される形でしたので、違う現象だと思っています。
自宅、会社どちらのPCでも同じ現象だったので投稿した次第ですが、もうひとつ別のPCではちゃんと表示されているのを確認しましたので、その差が何なのかもうちょっと調べてみようと思います。